# How to check equality of enums with values

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following enums:

```
enum BulletinOption {
    case notifications
    case share(type: EventType)
}

enum EventType {
    case singleEvent(position: Int, text: String)
    case multipleEvents(text: String)
}
```

I create an array of enums like:

```
var options: [BulletinOption] = [
    .notifications,
    .share(type: .singleEvent(position: 8, text: "My text"))
]
```

What I want to do is check whether the options array contains the `.share` enum (doesn't matter about the type associated with it), and replace it with a different type of `.share` enum.

e.g.

```
if options.contains(BulletinOption.share) {
    // find position of .share and replace it 
    // with .share(type: .multipleEvents(text: "some text"))
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access array index and object both then you can use `for case` with your `options` array.

```
for case let (index,BulletinOption.share(_)) in options.enumerated() {
    //Change value here
    options[index] = .share(type: .multipleEvents(text: "some text"))

    //You can also break the loop if you want to change for only first search object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He is the trick :

```
extension BulletinOption: Equatable {
   static func ==(lhs: BulletinOption, rhs: BulletinOption) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.notifications, .notifications):
            return true
        case (.share(_), .share(_)):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I use this to check whether the array contains the `.share` enum case, and the index of the enum in the array?

Comment: you can do `myArray.index(of: BulletinOption.share(type: Eventype.smthg))`